# scp changing permissions on /tmp directory

Tags: permissions, tar, scp

I use an expect script to automate transfer of some support files onto terminals. The support files are automatically tarballed before being scp'ed onto the target terminal. This is accomplished by an in-house expect program that automatically fills out the password for the scp so we don't have to put the password in. I can copy the individual files without issue, but when I try to copy the tar.gz file, it changes the permissions of the /tmp directory. I have been chmodding the /tmp directory back to 1777 for the permissions and chowning it to root.root, which is how it is normally set up, but this doesn't always work. It is causing sqlite errors due to sqlite not being able to write a temp file to /tmp, which is very disruptive. How can I determine the exact cause of this? I know it has to be related to the tar.gz file, but I was under the impression that tar would preserve the permissions on the file.

the permissions on the file inside my directory are:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 aembree aembree  88K Oct  2 15:20 dropin.tar.gz
```

Before the transfer /tmp looks like this in an ls -al:

```
drwxrwxrwt  15 root root 8.4K Oct  2 15:08 tmp
```

After the transfer /tmp looks like this:

```
drwxrwxr-x  15 10539 10539 8.4K Oct  2 15:01 tmp
```

The tar command being run is the following:

```
tar -vPczf /home/aembree/bin/resources/dev/dropin.tar.gz --exclude='helperscript' -C $dropinlist . > /home/aembree/bin/resources/logs/tarlog
```

Once the file is on the remote machine, expect executes the following command to unpack it:

```
send "cd /tmp ; tar -xzf dropin.tar.gz ; rm dropin.tar.gz ; cd ;\n"
```

Comment: Can you share the expect script? or at least the exact tar and scp commands executed?

Comment: I cannot access the source of the expect script that does the transfer, it is hidden away somewhere that makes me think I'm not supposed to be able to see it :/ I will add the tar command being run to the op

Comment: As `scp` never does it, the problem is in the script.

Comment: and yet that script only has trouble with my archive file. it never changes permissions of /tmp when transferring any other file

Comment: I bet your tarball was created from ./ so when it is extracted it overrides the current directory's (./) permissions.

Comment: Do you really need to provide a password to `scp` or can you set up certificate based authentication? It would help reduce the need for an expect script and you wouldn't need to leave the password in plain sight either.

Answer (score 7):

You've included `.` in your source collection given to `tar`. The problem occurs when you extract the tarball and the permissions are applied. Your source directory `.` is extracted and permissions applied. Unfortunately at the point of extraction `.` is actually `/tmp`.

The fix is either to exclude `.` from the tarball or to create a temporary directory within `/tmp` in which to extract it all.

Comment: this appears to be the correct answer. I changed my tar command to 

tar -czvf /home/aembree/bin/resources/dev/dropin.tar.gz --directory="/home/aembree/bin/resources/dropins" $dropinlist > /home/aembree/bin/resources/logs/tarlog

and it no longer changes permissions on /tmp when transferred in. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @AbbyEmbree if this answer works for you please remember to tick it to show this